# PHP error - cannot redeclare function

Tags: php

I have a JavaScript function making a call to a PHP script.  So far so good.  A problem happens when I try to do this:

```
$hike_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['hike_id']);
```

When I import my connection file, it gives me an error that the functions in that file have already been defined and the error is this:

```
[Fri Jun 10 12:34:43 2011] [error] [client 75.24.105.18] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare hassuspicioushackerstrings() (previously declared in /home/webadmin/comehike.com/html/connect.php:16) in /home/webadmin/comehike.com/html/connect.php on line 40
```

The error it is referring to is a function that is in the connect script.

But if I remove the

```
include '../connect.php';
```

Then it will just tell me that I can not use the mysql_real_escape_string function. So I am kind of stuck between not being able to use either option.

Comment: You seem to be including the file that declares `hassuspicioushackerstrings()`. I don't think this has to do with mysql_real_escape_string()

Answer (score 13, accepted):

try `include_once '../connect.php';` it'll make sure you're only including once this file

Comment: the include_once thing did the trick - thank you!

Comment: @Genadinik you should also read what @Fosco wrote about your error. Try to fix your error by redoing your program logic, `include_once` and `required_once` aren't ideal as both consume valuable system resources to figure out if a file is already included/required or not.

Comment: In some cases there may be an extra include statement within one of the children php files, that is where I found my error. The incude_once doesn't help in these situations.

Comment: @grantzukowski no it doesn't as `include_once()` checks to see if the file you're trying to load is already included, it doesn't search your code recursively (it makes no sense to search recursively)

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at your files and your includes...  You are declaring that function twice, that is the error.  It has nothing to do with MySQL, database connections, or mysql_real_escape_string().

I.e. You may be including file A and file B, but file A already includes file B... You can either figure out where your includes are going wrong, or use `include_once` or `require_once` to prevent it from double-loading.

Answer (score 2):

Likely you are including the file multiple times. Use require_once instead of include.

Answer (score 1):

you cant use mysql_real_escape_string() because connect.php is most likely setting up your database connection. My guess is there is another include (perhaps 'functions.php') that has the same function.

You probably have something like this:

function hassuspicioushackerstrings($input) {
}

in your connect.php, you could add `if(!function_exists('hassuspicioushackerstrings')) {` and `}` around the function.

Answer (score 0):

Never create or declare a function inside another function. But you can still use other functions inside a function. For example the following is not right

```
function addition($a, $b)
{
    function subtraction(){
    }
    return $a+$b;
}
```